# Custom property pages not titled in Outlook 2003

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I am implementing a custom Outlook Property page in C++ as an ActiveX control as per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206741%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Basically, I have noticed that when passing an initialized object (my ActiveX object) to the 'raw_add' method on the property pages obtained within the namespace event 'OpetionsPagesAdd', the second parameter (the property page tab title) is ignored in Outlook 2003. In 2007 and 2010 my code works absolutely fine, only in 2003 does that second parameter seem to be ignored.

I'm sure I have come across articles in the past describing this as a known bug in Outlook 2003, but I was wandering if anyone had found a way around the issue? I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PropertyPages.aspx) describing the same issue, and the resolution, but that is for C#, and I can't for the life of me see how to port his 'fix' to C++.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up raising a support case with Microsoft for this issue, and it is a bug in Outlook 2003. The way around it is to derive from public IDispatchImpl and define the caption property in the prop map:
  ( PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Caption", DISPID_CAPTION, CLSID_PropPage, VT_BSTR)

Then implement the put_caption and get_caption methods and it should work.